No Point Cloud Output When using depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb in ROS
I'm trying to publish a /calculated_veg topic of type sensor_msgs/Image into a point cloud named /calculated_veg/points using the depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb package in ROS, but I am not getting any point cloud output. Here is my launch file:
<launch>
  <!-- Start the nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" args="manager"
    output="screen"/>
  
  <!-- Load the point_cloud_xyzrgb nodelet -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="point_cloud_xyzrgb" args="load
      depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb nodelet_manager" output="screen">
    <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/color/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="rgb/image_rect_color" to="/calculated_veg"/>
    <remap from="depth_registered/image_rect"
      to="/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="depth_registered/points" to="/calculated_veg/points"/>
  </node>
</launch>

After running this launch file, I do not see any point cloud being published on the /calculated_veg/points topic. I have verified that the /calculated_veg topic is publishing images correctly. Here is an example of the /calculated_veg image:
an example of the /calculated_veg image
Additional Information:

ROS Distribution: ROS1 Noetic
Operating System: Ubuntu Focal (20.04)
The /calculated_veg topic is calculated using the RGB image and the infrared image, which are already aligned to the RGB camera frame.
All images are obtained from the Intel RealSense D435i camera. To execute the camera, I use the following command:

roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch enable_infra1:=true align_depth:=true

Can anyone help me identify what might be going wrong or suggest troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue? Thank you!

have you also verified the other input topics, directly from the camera?

@ChristianFritz Yes, other topics from the camera, including RGB, infrared, and depth images along with their respective camera information, have been verified.
